# How can I turn an asp:textbox into a multiline <textarea>?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using an ASP textbox as a textarea, which I recognize is rendered as an HTML `<input type=text>`. It has thus far served its intended purpose, with the exception that I cannot get the text to wrap or start at the top.

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:textbox id="Message_Box" runat="server" mode="multiline" form="Feedback_Form" CssClass="Contact_Input" maxlength="1200" lines="10" cols="10" wrap="true"  />
```

and my CSS:

```css
#Main_Box_Left form textarea, #Main_Box_Left form .Contact_Input {
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    height:228px;
    width:453px;
    max-width:455px;
    max-height:230px;
    min-height:230px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:20px;   
    color:rgb(63,69,73);
    font-family:Arapey;
    font-weight:lighter;
    min-width:455px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:#fcfcfc;
    border:1px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-top:1px solid #191919;
    border-left:1px solid #191919;
}
```

The "lines", "cols", and "wrap" tags in the ASP component seemingly do nothing.

If there is an alternative tag I should be using as a text area, please advise. If there is a way to wrap the text/make it start at the top, that would be fantastic as well.

Comment: Do you have an example of the text not wrapping or starting at the top? Screenshot?

Comment: By the way `MaxLength` is ignored when `TextMode="MultiLine"`. It should also be `Rows` instead of `lines` and `Columns` instead of `cols`. I am actually shocked that your textarea rendered anywhere close to what you showed in the screenshot with your original attribute names on your ASP.NET TextBox control.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Change `mode="multiline"`  to `TextMode="MultiLine"` this will render a `textarea` element